# How to open an external file from a Colab Jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a Jupyter notebook in which I create an HTML file. I then open this HTML file in a new browser tab.

It's an R analysis, so I opened the HTML file using `browseURL()`.

However, when I use a Colab hosted version of the notebook, nothing happens when I try to open the page.

Here's a reproducible example: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BfVDsDnXQwEpy4HwPKWkUC9Bpaz6r0Kv

Other things I tried that didn't work:

1. Using `system2()` instead of `browseURL()`.
2. Setting the browser option to the `open` system tool via `options(browser = "/usr/bin/open")`.

Is there another value for `browser` I should use? Is there a permission setting I should change?

Otherwise, how can I get the Colab notebook to display the HTML page I created?

Comment: Not a real answer, but for the record I went with "use Binder instead of Colab".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Colab stores its files in Google Drive and judging by this [link](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/8332195?hl=en&msgid=12851850), Google doesn't support serving HTML from there.

You could save them as `png` files and display them like this if you're OK to have to install a few extra libraries.

```
install.packages('webshot')
webshot::install_phantomjs()
library(webshot)
webshot('https://www.halfbakery.com/', 'hb.png', delay = 2)

install.packages("png")
library(png)
img <- readPNG('hb.png')
grid::grid.raster(img)
```

I have tried it in Colab and it works there. I should add that `browseURL` still doesn't work on the file although double clicking on the file in the Files page does bring up a window with the png correctly displayed.